# Dense Subset of $L^{2n}$ for Range of the distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I am selecting a distribution for MIT-BIH arrhythmia data that is ECG data which follows AAMI standards.
Let distribution $A$ : $D(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that

\begin{equation}
A : D(\mathbb{R}) \to L^{2}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})
\end{equation}
but because the digital signal that is all frequencies above Nyquist frequency are removed, I would choose and make the signal bounded above by redefining
\begin{equation}
A : D(\mathbb{R}) \to D(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}).
\end{equation}
where $D(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}) \subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$.

The distribution $A$ is like Wigner-Ville Distribution but Quadratic.
It is quadratic nonlinear Time-Frequency Representation.

**Is there any sense of selecting the range dense here for ECG signal?**